# No plugin icon in the toolbox in QGis 2.4

Tags: python, pyqgis, qgis-2.4, toolbar, icon

When i'm loading my plugin into QGis 2.4 the icon doesn't appear in the toolbar. There is only an empty button. I have the icon.png in all the necessary files:

resources.py:

```
<RCC>
     <qresource prefix="/plugins/colorTransparency" >
        <file>icon.png</file>
     </qresource>
</RCC>
```

which is compiled with pyrcc4 -o resources.py resources.qrc

metadata.txt:

```
icon=icon.png
```

colorTransparency:

```
 def initGui(self):
    # Create action that will start plugin configuration
    self.action = QAction(
        QIcon(":/plugins/colorTransparency/icon.png"),
        u"Transparency and Random Color", self.iface.mainWindow())
    #connect the action to the run method
    self.action.triggered.connect(self.run)

    # Add toolbar button and menu item
    self.iface.addToolBarIcon(self.action)
    self.iface.addPluginToMenu(u"&TransparencyRandomColor", self.action)

def unload(self):
    # Remove the plugin menu item and icon
    self.iface.removePluginMenu(u"&TransparencyRandomColor", self.action)
    self.iface.removeToolBarIcon(self.action)
```

The icon.png is in the same directory and has a size of 25px x 25px.

In the plugin installer the icon is displayed.
I also tried to delete it and clean everything but it doesn't work.

Comment: did you compiled the resource file with Make (in case of Plugin Builder) or using directly pyrcc4 compiler?

Comment: I've tried it with make. This did not work. Afterwards I deleted the .py file and exectued pyrcc4 manually.

Comment: if your read the make, if try to compile resources.rc giving it name as resources_rc.py => purcc4 -o resources_rc.py resources.rc. the output .py have to be the same imported in the plugin

Comment: Ok i did it like this and it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for me was not to use the **Plugin Builder** Plugin that is recommended in the PYQgis Cookbook.

When I create the files manually everything is working fine and the icon is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.Try picture resolution 24x24 and with less shades of color.

Comment: I tried it with 24x24 and a simple black square but it has no effect in the toolbox.